# How to Deploy Resource to Hive in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: deployment, resources, localization, sharepoint-2010

I've read a lot of examples and tutorials about it. But none of the so called solutions helped me in my case.

**Problem**:
I have multiple web parts using the same resource files, so there is a solution for resource files that has a mapped folder to Resources with resx files in it.

When I deploy with resx file's "build action" property set to embedded or none, resources are not deployed to Hive/Resources.

---

When I deploy with "build action" set to "content", resources are deployed but the webparts that use resources get the error below:

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "ResourceWp.Resources.ListNames.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "ResourceWp" at compile time,
>   or that all the satellite assemblies
>   required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

This is the place where my last healthy nerves couldn't resist the pain. I want to use the resx file neutral in culture like any simple asp.net webApp. I think something really simple is here that I'm missing because of my lack of knowledge about the assembly usage.

---

Through all the reading, I just couldn't understand one point that if I am able to use resource files like super.resx without writing super.en-US.resx (neutral I mean).

Because only difference that I have is this point, I don't use any tr-TR or likewise culture identifier and I use this project in a Turkish language-pack installed and in a site created by selecting "Turkish" as language.

But in my opinion, that shouldn't be the point, right?

---

**Summary:**
I want to deploy my resource in Hive/Resources and them to be available to my webparts

I have tried:

- http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/working-with-resource-files-in-sharepoint-2010/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/jevgeni/archive/2010/02/02/using-resource-files-in-sharepoint-2010-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx

kind of approaches. But didn't accomplish any success with them.

I hope, someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't believe that there's nobody uses resources for sharepoint. I assumed that would be an easy question. If it's not possible, please let me know and I shall close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as it is necessary to place the resource files in App_GlobalResources folder. This approach worked well in my (similar) case: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20851/localizing-asp-markup-in-webpart-issue